# Python chat client-server modification goes horribly wrong

Tags: python, client, chat

As an exercise, I looked for a simple Python chat client-server system to modify and toy with. The first major failing I found in the system was that it used a single tcp connection for the server and client to communicate. The second was that you could only have two people (one using the client, and the other using the server) communicate. Thirdly, consecutive posts were impossible. One person sent a message, then had to wait for the other person to send a single message before talking again. Very, very limiting.

So I began threading it and experimenting with the sockets. Clients connect to the server once, give their IP addresses, create a listening thread, and then reconnect to the server's message receiver.
All posts are sent to that receiver, which iterates through a list of connected clients and connects to each of them and sends the message (with the sender's name in the beginning; misc feature).
(I know that opening a new connection so often like that is inefficient, but I wanted to keep with tcp connections until I had it working, and THEN go to UDP)

However, weird crap began happening. Suffice it to say that I have nightmares of Error 91.

Could anyone identify how to render this code operable within this structure and feature-set?
(Python version 2.6 yey; ignore the infinite loop that is just a placeholder)

SERVER CODE:

```
from socket import *
from time import time, ctime
import Queue, threading

IP = ''  
PORT = 5000  
PORTPlus = 2  
PORTRec = 1000  
ADS = (IP, PORT)  
namelist = []  
clientlist = []  



class clientRec(threading.Thread):  
    def __init__(self):  
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)  
        print "I'm this far:", (IP, (PORT + PORTRec))  
        self.receiver = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)  
        self.receiver.bind((IP, PORT + PORTRec))  
        self.sender = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)  
    def run(self):  
        global clientlist, namelist  
        self.receiver.listen(10)  
        connected = True  
        while connected:  
            tcpcli, addr = receiver.accept()  
            message = tcpcli.recv(1024)                 # Accept clien't IP for   home-dialing  
            for i in range(clientlist.__len__()):               # For each connected client  
                try:  
                    sender.connect(clientlist(i))                 # connect  
                    sender.send(namelist[i] + message)         # and deliver message with sender's name  
                    sender.close()  
                except:  
                    del clientlist[i], namelist[i]  

print "ADS:", (IP, 5000)  
handle = clientRec()  
tcpsoc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)   # Paperwork  
tcpsoc.bind(ADS)                        # Bind self to port  
tcpsoc.listen(5)                        # Listen on that port0  
handle.start()                          # Start thread  

# Main  
while 1:  
    print "Waiting for connection"  
    tcpcli, addr = tcpsoc.accept()      # Accept unknown client  
    print "Connection received; handling..."  
    namelist.append(tcpcli.recv(1024))  # Accept client's name  
    client_IP = tcpcli.recv(1024)       # Accept clien't IP for home-dialing  
    client_port = int(tcpcli.recv(1024))# Accept clien't listening port  
    port_assign = PORT + PORTRec  
    tcpcli.send(str(port_assign))       # Tell the client that port  
    tcpcli.close()                      # Close client connection  

    clientlist.append((client_IP, client_port))# Add client to send-list  
    print "Handled."  

tcpsoc.close()
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from socket import *  
import threading, cgi, os  

IP = ''  
PORT = 5000  
PORTmy = 100  
ADS = (IP, PORT)  

class iListen(threading.Thread):  
    def __init__(self):  
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)  
        self.receiver = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)# Paperwork  
        self.receiver.bind(('', PORT + PORTmy))     # Listen on that port  
        self.receiver.listen(5)                     # Listen for posts  
    def run(self):  
        while listening:  
            tcpcli, addr = receiver.accept()        # Accept unknown client  
            message = tcpcli.recv(1024)  
            if message == "/q":  
                listening = False  
            tcpcli.close()  

# Initial CONNECT  
myname = raw_input("Tell me yer name partnah: ")  
tcpsoc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)  
tcpsoc.connect(ADS)                     # First Connect  
tcpsoc.send(myname)                     # Declare name  
tcpsoc.send(gethostbyname(gethostname()))# Give IP address  
tcpsoc.send(str(PORT + PORTmy))         # Give listening port  
ADS = (IP, int(tcpsoc.recv(1024)))      # Get new connect details  
tcpsoc.close()                          # Close old connection  
listen = iListen()                      # Create listener thread  
listen.start()                          # Start listening  

# RECONNECT  
print ADS  
tcpsoc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)  
tcpsoc.connect(ADS)                     # reconnect to new port  
connected = True  

# Main Chat-loop  
while connected:  
    mes = raw_input(">>>")  
    tcpsoc.send(mes)  
    if mes == "/q":  
        tcpsoc.close()  
        connected = False  
        time.sleep(4)  

sys.exit()
```

Comment: You might get lucky and have someone write your code for you here, but I doubt it, partnah. StackOverflow questions need to be a little more focused and look less like homework exercises.

Comment: UDP for chat? Haha good one! PS: Fixed the indentation...

Comment: instead of saying "weird crap began happening", you might want to explain the errors you are seeing in detail.  also, try to break this down to a simpler example to isolate the issue more.  it will be for your own benefit and also might make the question answerable.

Comment: ...you may also want to hit the 1010101 button there and reformat your code so it looks like code.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on something alot like this, but I am instead going to implement text encryption. I see you are suing lists for the client list... but I would say there is a better way of doing that. I am using a dictionary.

if you are familiar with dictionaries, skip the next paragraph.

Dicionaries can handle basicly 2 variables, and are defined using the {}.

```
>>> stuff = {'a':'hello','b':'world'}
>>> print stuff['a']
hello
>>> print stuff['a'],stuff['b']
hello world
```

so using this, you can can make a dictionary like {'username':'ipaddr'} this way you can make it so that both usernames and ips are all in one variable. If you want the end product like me, you will be making it so all the server does is repeat the message, and send it to everyone who is connected. then the server can just cycle through the usernames.

as another note, I think the tcpsoc.listen(5) is how many people can beconnected at once... I think thats what i read somewhere.

I have no idea why you would be having that error, but if you want to look at my halfway constucted code, you are more than welcome too. (ignore the import random, this is not yet used, but will be part of the encryption system)

http://piratepad.net/PwQzdU0bkk